# using OpenSSL command in my Kubernetes pod

Tags: docker

I have to execute few OpenSSL commands inside my Kubernetes pod. However, I get OpenSSL to command not found.
Below is my docker file.

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential cmake zlib1g-dev libcppunit-dev git subversion wget && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2g.tar.gz -O - | tar -xz
WORKDIR /openssl-1.0.2g
RUN ./config --prefix=/usr/local/openssl --openssldir=/usr/local/openssl && make && make install


FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
RUN addgroup -g 1000 -S spring && adduser -u 1000 -S spring -G spring 
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Can anyone please help me here?

Comment: Only the final build stage starting from the last `FROM` line is used.  Unless you `COPY --from=...` something from an earlier stage, nothing there is used, and in this Dockerfile the first stage is completely ignored.  Try using `apk add` in the final stage instead.

Comment: @DavidMaze , I am pretty new to docker. Could you help me with an example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following docker file helped me

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
RUN apk add --update openssl && \
rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
RUN addgroup -g 1000 -S spring && adduser -u 1000 -S spring -G spring
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Comment: is there a way to do this with python?